# problem 3.48 of Enderton's "Elements of Set Theory"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

### 0. problem 3.48

Problem. Let $T$ be the set $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.

(a) Find all of the ordered pairs, if any, in $\mathcal P T$.

(b) Evaluate and simplify: $(\mathcal P T)^{-1}\circ(\mathcal P T \upharpoonright \{\emptyset\})$

### 1. checking a solution

a solution of a person suggests the answer as $\emptyset$ for questions both 3.48(a) and (b).

(thanks for yunone.se@gmail.com)

because there are no ordered pairs in $\mathcal P T$, so all of the answers are $\emptyset$.

but I think that's not, because of the definition of ordered pair.

so I have a question.

### 2. definition of an ordered pair

an ordered pair $\left< x,y\right>$ is $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$.

because the following condition holds if we choose this definition:

$\left<x,y\right>=\left<a,b\right>$ if and only if $x=a\wedge y=b$.

### 3. special case when both elements are same

so we can construct all of ordered pairs in our semantic domain by the above definition.

I choose an ordered pair $\left<a,a\right>$ for an arbitrary $a$.

then $\left<a,a\right>=\{\{a\}\}$ because set contracts the duplicate members.

### 4. answer of 3.48(a)-(b).

by definition of $T$, $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\in \mathcal P T$.

but by the case 3. we have an ordered pair $\left<\emptyset,\emptyset\right>$.

therefore the answer of 3.48(a) is not $\emptyset$ but $\left<\emptyset,\emptyset\right>$.

likewise I can calculate 3.48(b).

$$
\begin{split}
(\mathcal P T)^{-1}\circ(\mathcal P T \upharpoonright \{\emptyset\}) &= \{\left<\emptyset,\emptyset\right>\}\circ\{\left<\emptyset,\emptyset\right>\}\\
&=\{\left<\emptyset,\emptyset\right>\}.
\end{split}
$$

of course It's not $\emptyset$.

### 5. my question.

did I infer correctly?

Comment: I agree that $\langle \emptyset,\emptyset\rangle$ is an element of the powerset of $T$.  I am not clear on what is intended by $(\mathcal{P}T)^{-1}$ since $\mathcal{P}T$ is not a relation (*it has $\emptyset$ as an element for instance which is not itself able to be interpreted as an ordered pair*)

Comment: in the Page 44 of the textbook, Enderton suggests definitions of inverse, composition, restriction, image to be allowed for arbitrary sets. in this definitions, inverse of a set equals to the inverse of the relation which delete out non-ordered pair elements from the set.

Comment: With the understanding that as soon as we apply inverse, or restriction and the like to these we force out any non-ordered pair elements, and with the understanding that we are accepting the same setup and assumptions as Enderton that we are defining ordered pairs via the kuratowski definition, then I agree with all of your analysis and answers.  Under a different set of definitions and assumptions then I can see how someone would arrive at a different answer which is equally correct, just they are answering a technically different problem than yours since context is a part of the problem.

Comment: I've just thought from your comment on different definitions are possible(e.g. Wiener, or simplified Kuratowski using the regularity axiom). in that cases the answer can be different to me.

Comment: Yes, but from the context that the exercise was being asked as a part of this particular textbook, and the author has stated clearly what definitions are being used throughout the course of the textbook, we are obligated to use the assumptions and definitions we are told to use by the author when considering any questions here.  That makes your answer right and any other answer wrong so long as the question remains labeled as coming from the textbook in question.  Only after the label and therefore the context of the problem is lost would other answers be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer and analysis is correct and shows that you have a good understanding of the definitions being used by the author in your textbook.  In particular that of ordered pairs and set operations involving ordered pairs.  It is a common mistake or shortcoming or intentional choice not to interpret sets as an ordered pair when not written as such, but the intent and point of the author here with this exercise is to test your knowledge on exactly this topic.